# Найти сумму элементов массива(в массиве ещё массивы)

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как найти сумму всех элементов массива (в массиве есть вложенные массивы)?

Например: `arr = [1,2,[2,5,3,[32,5],3],7,4...]` неограниченное количество вложенности массивов в массиве,

Comment: @Air, рискую навлечь гнев сообщества, но, ИМХО, получив ответ, студент бегом побежал сдавать "лабу", забыв своих благодетелей. Думаю, что на следующий день будет забыта и рекурсия и JavaScript. Мораль - не нужно помогать решать учебные задачи, если студент не демонстрирует попыток ее самостоятельного решения.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, я с тобой согласен, но мы чего-то перестали пресекать  оплодотворение подобных вопросов одноразовых  участников....

Comment: @Air там в ответах понаставили много плюсов и один мой минус ничего не решит. Но и нужно отдать должное, что ответ через лямбды хорош.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, а с другой стороны, черт с ними с этими `одноразками`, коллеги старались, да и завтра у меня на пример возникнет вопрос, а он уже готов....  Если у человека нет тяги к познанию, то шпору он всегда найдет....))))

Comment: Задал вопрос не для сдачи лабы,а просто интересно стало,как это сделать.Оставил вопрос и ушел на работу,вернулся - увидел ответ,спасибо за то,что не оставили его без внимания!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1,2,[2,5,3,[32,5],3],7,4];

const sum = arr => arr.reduce((res, el) => res + (Array.isArray(el) ? sum(el) : el), 0);

console.log(sum(arr));
```

Answer (score 7):

С помощью рекурсивного метода.

*Проверяем каждый элемент.

 Если это массив вызываем функцию, передавая в параметр сам элемент.*

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [2, 5, 3, [32, 5], 3], 7, 4];
var sum = 0;

function foo(array) {

  array.forEach(function(value, index) {
    Array.isArray(value) ? foo(value) : sum += value; 
  });

  return sum;
}

console.log(foo(arr));
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [2, 5, 3, [32, 5, [23, 6, [3, 8, 0, [13]]]], 3], 7, 4];

function iterator(arr, callback) {
  var item;
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    item = arr[j];

    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      iterator(item, callback);
    } else {
      callback(item);
    }
  }
}
var data = [];

function callback(item) {
  data.push(item)
}

iterator(arr, callback);
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  total = total + data[i];
}

console.log(total)
```

Comment: а что за алгоритм у вас?@Puvvl

Comment: @Избытоксусликов обычное условие, если в массиве есть вложенность то он вызывает снова `iterator` и передает ему эту вложенность после чего вызывает функция callback которая записывает число в отдельную переменную.

Comment: @Puvvl, [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: @Puvvl спасибо за обяснения .

Comment: @Deonis спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

все очень просто. Вложенность убирается  `join`; , а дальше просто суммировать. Ну и не забыть почистить.

```
function sumJaggedArray(array){
  return [...array.join``].map(x=>parseFloat(x)).filter(e=>e>0).
  reduce((a,e)=>a+e,0);
}
```

Comment: Гениально использовать `join`

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [1, 2, [2, 5, 3, [32, 5], 3], 7, 4];

const sum = (arr) => {
return arr.flat(Infinity).reduce((accum, item) => accum + item, 0);
};

console.log(sum(arr)); // Выведет сумму всех элементов в массиве arr
```